# More addresses per customer from admin panel is not getting saved in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am trying to add more than 50 addresses for one customer but after 55 addresses it is not getting saved. The page getting crashed, after some time page gets load shows the success message for customer saving but address is not getting saved.

Tried almost all the way but not get any luck. Could any one please suggest anything on this ?

Thanks,
Jen

Comment: Try this in multiple browsers. It could be an issue with the JavaScript portion of the ajax save. This is a problem when you have a ridiculous amount of attributes on a product/customer/category as well. Let us know what happens!

Comment: Check your server setting for `max_input_vars` limit, or if `suhosin` patch is used which could limit the number of post variables allowed.

Comment: @Nick M - We are having the 5-6 extra attribute on product and customer nothing else.

Comment: @subtroutines - Thanks for your answer. But i don't have any idea about suhosin. I will check for max_input_vars.